# Ive got a weird Symfony Login redirect issue, looks like its a session issue, anyone got any ideas?

Tags: php, symfony, cookies

I have got a v weird issue with one of my symfony ( 2.8) apps, out of nowhere the login just stopped working, submitting the login form just brought me back to login page again, no bad credentials error and no system issue warning.
I looked at my cookies in the browser , as this worked in incognito mode, and i had 2 PHPSESSID, is this normal? removing the cookies allowed me to log in again with no issue. am trying to get to the bottom of how to reproduce this as its not something i want to go into my production env

here is the current security yml:

```
security:
acl:
    connection: default
encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_USER:        ROLE_USER
    ROLE_CLIENT_PROGRAMME_ADMIN: ROLE_CLIENT_PROGRAMME_ADMIN
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_PROGAMME_ADMIN
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN

providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email

firewalls:
    oauth_token:
        pattern:    ^/oauth/v2/token
        anonymous: true

    api:
        pattern:    ^/api
        fos_oauth:  true
        stateless:  true
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: security.csrf.token_manager # Use form.csrf_provider instead for Symfony <2.4
            success_handler: auth.service.redirect.after.login

        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true


access_control:
    - { path: ^/oauth/v2/token, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/user/password/reset$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/docs$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/login, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/api/$, roles: [ROLE_USER] }
    - { path: ^/client, roles: [ROLE_CLIENT_PROGRAMME_ADMIN, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN] }
    - { path: ^/portal, roles: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN] }
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN] }
    - { path: ^/, roles: [SECTION_CHECK, ROLE_PROGAMME_ADMIN, ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN] }
```

Comment: I'd guess you had two cookies for different subdomains?

Comment: / and app_dev.php/ and app running on localhost:8888

Comment: Can you show your security configuration?

Comment: added the config, cheers